# What does typescript "interface | interface | function" syntax mean?

Tags: typescript, openapi-generator

I am using the openapi-generator-cli with typescirpt-fetch generator to generate models for my application.
I am having issues with parts of the generated code that referees to the field that is a polymorphic class.
The generated code has an error that reads:

```
TS2693: 'ItineraryButtonDTO' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.
```

I am trying to understand what is causing this. But I am not sure what does code in question even means:

```
'buttons': !exists(json, 'buttons') ? undefined : ((json['buttons'] as Array<any>).map(ItineraryButtonDTO | FlightNotificationButtonDTO | ItineraryPayloadButtonDTO | ItineraryPersonaButtonDTOFromJSON)),
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was an issue with the fetch-typescript generator producing not valid code.
There is an open ticket on their github page
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/4626